Loading native library on Android and iOS using .NET MAUI
I am trying to load MyCLib.so on Android and use __Internal on iOS. But it throws "DllNotFoundException" on Android and crashes right away on iOS. After many attempts, I added DllImportResolver which caused no change at all. This code can load libSkiaSharp.so but it can't load my native library which is present in correct abi folder in apk. Even, it is next to the skiasharp library.
public partial class App : Application
  {
    private static IntPtr DllImportResolver(string libraryName, Assembly assembly, DllImportSearchPath? searchPath)
    {
      if (libraryName == "MyCLib")
      {
        if (OperatingSystem.IsAndroid())
        {
          return NativeLibrary.Load("libMyCLib.so", assembly, searchPath);
        }
        if (OperatingSystem.IsIOS())
        {
          return NativeLibrary.Load(@"__Internal", assembly, searchPath);
        }

      }

      // Otherwise, fallback to default import resolver.
      return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public App()
    {
      NativeLibrary.SetDllImportResolver(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyCLibWrapper.MyCLib)), DllImportResolver);
      InitializeComponent();
      MyCLibWrapper.MyCLib a = new();
      int b = a.CallMain();
      MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
  }

Here is my CMake Presets
    {
      "name": "android-arm64",
      "inherits": "default",
      "description": "Configuration for Android ARM64",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/android-arm64",
      "toolchainFile": "${sourceDir}/cmake/android-arm64.cmake",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME": "Android",
        "CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI": "arm64-v8a",
        "CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK": "~/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125",
        "CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE": "c++_shared",
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "ios-arm64",
      "inherits": "default",
      "description": "Configuration for iOS ARM64",
      "generator": "Xcode",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/ios-arm64",
      "toolchainFile": "${sourceDir}/cmake/ios-arm64.cmake",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME": "iOS",
        "CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES": "arm64",
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
        "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS": "off"
      }
    }

And toolchain for
Android:
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI arm64-v8a)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 21)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\ndk\\26.1.10909125")
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\\ndk\\26.1.10909125\\build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake")


did you find a solution to this issue
